# Ubuntu affects Windows headphone

Tags: windows, headphones

I am dual booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04  I went to listen to my headphones in Windows and could hear nothing.  I could hear through the speakers fine. I plugged the headphones in, Windows detected the headphones had been plugged in, but there was no sound.  I looked on a different forum where someone said they muted the sound in Linux and the headphones worked in Windows.  I tried it, and I have the same thing.  Why would this be and is there a way to stop Ubuntu from influencing my headphones in Windows?

Comment: Did you check to see if Windows is muting (or turning down) the sound when headphones are plugged in?  Are they USB headphones?  If so, did you switch the primary sound device to the headphones?

Comment: They are just normal headphones, and I did not see anywhere to turn down headphone apart from the main volume